Difficulty Compiling NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02.run file under Ubuntu 24.10
I am trying to run the NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02.run file under Ubuntu 24.10 in a tty terminal (with all the GUI terminals closed) in order to install a better driver for the NVIDIA QUADRO K600 (where currently DVI works great on the card, but the DP Display Port does not work at all). Strangely enough, there is no kernel driver in use:
stephen@stephen-All-Series:~$ lspci
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GL [Quadro K600] (rev a1)

stephen@stephen-All-Series:~$ lspci -v -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GL [Quadro K600] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 094b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

There is an article How to Select Kernel Use for GPU which suggests that the kernel might be selected.  However, this article How to unbind a gpu /sys/bus/pci has a problem that the "/sys/bus/pci/driver/nvidia/" folder is not found, and indeed even only the "/sys/bus/pci/drivers" directory exists.
My computer's configuration is:
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-12-26 12:20:38

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              ASUS All Series
- **Memory:**                                      4.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i3-4170 × 4
- **Graphics:**                                    Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
- **Disk Capacity:**                               1.0 TB

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            1103
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               47
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.11.0-13-generic

I logged out of all of the Knome graphics displays to get to login windows or terminals which could be accessed with Ctrl-Alt-F1, Ctrl-Alt-F2, installed gcc and make and then was able to get to the stage of running the "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02.run" file from the terminal as root.  The resulting log file is very log, so I am just showing the head and tail entries.  The file itself is 1.56 MB, so here is just the beginning and end:
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Thu Dec 26 12:13:00 2024
installer version: 470.256.02

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface
-> Detected 4 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 4.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 470.256.02.
-> An alternate method of installing the NVIDIA driver was detected. (This is usually a package provided by your distributor.) A driver installed via that method may integrate better with your system than a driver installed by nvidia-installer.

Please review the message provided by the maintainer of this alternate installation method and decide how to proceed:

The NVIDIA driver provided by Ubuntu can be installed by launching the "Software & Updates" application, and by selecting the NVIDIA driver from the "Additional Drivers" tab.


(Answer: Continue installation)
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="/usr/bin/cc".
-> Performing CC check.
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/build'
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/build'
-> Performing Compiler check.
-> Performing Dom0 check.
-> Performing Xen check.
-> Performing PREEMPT_RT check.
-> Performing vgpu_kvm check.
-> Cleaning kernel module build directory.
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; /usr/bin/make -k -j4 clean NV_EXCLUDE_KERNEL_MODULES="" SYSSRC="/lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/build" SYSOUT="/lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/build"'...
   rm -f -r conftest
   make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.11.0-13-generic'
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.11.0-13-generic'
-> Building kernel modules
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; /usr/bin/make -k -j4  NV_EXCLUDE_KERNEL_MODULES="" SYSSRC="/lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/build" SYSOUT="/lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/build"'...
   make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.11.0-13-generic'
   warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
     The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-14 (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2) 14.2.0
     You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2) 14.2.0
     SYMLINK /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
    CONFTEST: hash__remap_4k_pfn
    CONFTEST: set_pages_uc
    CONFTEST: list_is_first
    CONFTEST: set_memory_uc
    CONFTEST: set_memory_array_uc
    CONFTEST: set_pages_array_uc
    CONFTEST: acquire_console_sem
    CONFTEST: console_lock
    CONFTEST: ioremap_cache
    CONFTEST: ioremap_wc
    CONFTEST: acpi_walk_namespace
    CONFTEST: sg_alloc_table
    CONFTEST: pci_get_domain_bus_and_slot
    CONFTEST: get_num_physpages
    CONFTEST: efi_enabled
    CONFTEST: pde_data
    CONFTEST: PDE_DATA
    CONFTEST: proc_remove
    CONFTEST: pm_vt_switch_required
    CONFTEST: xen_ioemu_inject_msi
    CONFTEST: phys_to_dma
    CONFTEST: get_dma_ops
    CONFTEST: dma_attr_macros
    CONFTEST: dma_map_page_attrs
    CONFTEST: write_cr4
    CONFTEST: of_get_property
    CONFTEST: of_find_node_by_phandle
    CONFTEST: of_node_to_nid
    CONFTEST: pnv_pci_get_npu_dev
    CONFTEST: of_get_ibm_chip_id
    CONFTEST: node_end_pfn
    CONFTEST: pci_bus_address
    CONFTEST: pci_stop_and_remove_bus_device
    CONFTEST: pci_remove_bus_device
    CONFTEST: register_cpu_notifier
    CONFTEST: cpuhp_setup_state
    CONFTEST: dma_map_resource
    CONFTEST: backlight_device_register
    CONFTEST: get_backlight_device_by_name
    CONFTEST: timer_setup
    CONFTEST: pci_enable_msix_range
    CONFTEST: kernel_read_has_pointer_pos_arg
    CONFTEST: kernel_write
    CONFTEST: kthread_create_on_node
    CONFTEST: of_find_matching_node
    CONFTEST: dev_is_pci
    CONFTEST: dma_direct_map_resource
    CONFTEST: tegra_get_platform
    CONFTEST: tegra_bpmp_send_receive
    CONFTEST: flush_cache_all
    CONFTEST: vmf_insert_pfn
    CONFTEST: jiffies_to_timespec
    CONFTEST: ktime_get_raw_ts64
    CONFTEST: ktime_get_real_ts64
    CONFTEST: full_name_hash
    CONFTEST: hlist_for_each_entry
    CONFTEST: pci_enable_atomic_ops_to_root
    CONFTEST: vga_tryget
    CONFTEST: pgprot_decrypted
    CONFTEST: cc_mkdec
    CONFTEST: iterate_fd
    CONFTEST: seq_read_iter
    CONFTEST: sg_page_iter_page
    CONFTEST: unsafe_follow_pfn
    CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_get
    CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_put_unlocked
    CONFTEST: set_close_on_exec
    CONFTEST: dma_set_coherent_mask
    CONFTEST: acpi_bus_get_device
    CONFTEST: get_task_ioprio
    CONFTEST: address_space_init_once
    CONFTEST: kbasename
    CONFTEST: vzalloc
    CONFTEST: wait_on_bit_lock_argument_count
    CONFTEST: bitmap_clear
    CONFTEST: usleep_range
    CONFTEST: radix_tree_empty
    CONFTEST: radix_tree_replace_slot
    CONFTEST: pnv_npu2_init_context
    CONFTEST: cpumask_of_node
    CONFTEST: acpi_video_backlight_use_native
    CONFTEST: drm_dev_unref
    CONFTEST: drm_reinit_primary_mode_group
    CONFTEST: get_user_pages_remote
    CONFTEST: get_user_pages
    CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_lookup
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_state_ref_counting
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_prime_res_obj
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_connector_dpms
    CONFTEST: drm_connector_funcs_have_mode_in_name
    CONFTEST: drm_framebuffer_get
    CONFTEST: drm_dev_put
    CONFTEST: drm_format_num_planes
    CONFTEST: drm_connector_for_each_possible_encoder
    CONFTEST: drm_rotation_available
    CONFTEST: drm_vma_offset_exact_lookup_locked
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_of_node_to_nid
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_sme_active
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_swiotlb_map_sg_attrs
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_swiotlb_dma_ops
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present___close_fd
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_close_fd
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_get_unused_fd
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_get_unused_fd_flags
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_nvhost_get_default_device
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_nvhost_syncpt_unit_interface_get_byte_offset
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_nvhost_syncpt_unit_interface_get_aperture
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_tegra_dce_register_ipc_client
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_tegra_dce_unregister_ipc_client
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_tegra_dce_client_ipc_send_recv
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_dram_clk_to_mc_clk
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_get_dram_num_channels
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_tegra_dram_types
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_screen_info
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_screen_info
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_kthread_create_on_node
    CONFTEST: acpi_op_remove
    CONFTEST: file_operations
    CONFTEST: file_inode
    CONFTEST: kuid_t
    CONFTEST: dma_ops
    CONFTEST: swiotlb_dma_ops
    CONFTEST: noncoherent_swiotlb_dma_ops
    CONFTEST: vm_fault_has_address
    CONFTEST: backlight_properties_type
    CONFTEST: vm_insert_pfn_prot
    CONFTEST: vmf_insert_pfn_prot
    CONFTEST: vm_ops_fault_removed_vma_arg
    CONFTEST: vmbus_channel_has_ringbuffer_page
    CONFTEST: device_driver_of_match_table
    CONFTEST: device_of_node
    CONFTEST: node_states_n_memory
    CONFTEST: kmem_cache_has_kobj_remove_work
    CONFTEST: sysfs_slab_unlink
    CONFTEST: proc_ops
    CONFTEST: timespec64
    CONFTEST: vmalloc_has_pgprot_t_arg
    CONFTEST: acpi_fadt_low_power_s0
    CONFTEST: mm_has_mmap_lock
    CONFTEST: pci_channel_state
    CONFTEST: num_registered_fb
    CONFTEST: vm_area_struct_has_const_vm_flags
    CONFTEST: address_space
    CONFTEST: backing_dev_info
    CONFTEST: mm_context_t
    CONFTEST: vm_fault_t
    CONFTEST: mmu_notifier_ops_invalidate_range
    CONFTEST: drm_bus_present
    CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_bus_type
    CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_irq
    CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_name
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_device_list
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_legacy_dev_list
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_set_busid
    CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_connectors_changed
    CONFTEST: drm_init_function_args
    CONFTEST: drm_helper_mode_fill_fb_struct
    CONFTEST: drm_master_drop_has_from_release_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_unload_has_int_return_type
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_crtc_destroy_state_has_crtc_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_plane_destroy_state_has_plane_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_mode_object_find_has_file_priv_arg
    CONFTEST: dma_buf_owner
    CONFTEST: drm_connector_list_iter
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_swap_state_has_stall_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_prime_flag_present
    CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_has_resv
    CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_async_flip
    CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_pageflip_flags
    CONFTEST: drm_format_modifiers_present
    CONFTEST: drm_vma_node_is_allowed_has_tag_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_vma_offset_node_has_readonly
    CONFTEST: drm_display_mode_has_vrefresh
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_master_set_has_int_return_type
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_free_object
    CONFTEST: drm_prime_pages_to_sg_has_drm_device_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_prime_callbacks
    CONFTEST: drm_crtc_atomic_check_has_atomic_state_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_vmap_has_map_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_plane_atomic_check_has_atomic_state_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_device_has_pdev
    CONFTEST: drm_mode_config_has_allow_fb_modifiers
    CONFTEST: dma_resv_add_fence
    CONFTEST: dma_resv_reserve_fences
    CONFTEST: reservation_object_reserve_shared_has_num_fences_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_connector_has_override_edid
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_dumb_destroy
    CONFTEST: drm_unlocked_ioctl_flag_present
    CONFTEST: dom0_kernel_present
    CONFTEST: nvidia_vgpu_kvm_build
    CONFTEST: nvidia_grid_build
    CONFTEST: nvidia_grid_csp_build
    CONFTEST: pm_runtime_available
    CONFTEST: pci_class_multimedia_hd_audio
    CONFTEST: drm_available
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_available
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_refcount_inc
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_refcount_dec_and_test
    CONFTEST: drm_alpha_blending_available
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_drm_gem_prime_fd_to_handle
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_drm_gem_prime_handle_to_fd
    CONFTEST: ib_peer_memory_symbols
     SYMLINK /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia/nv.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia/nv-pci.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia/nv-acpi.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia/nv-cray.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/conftest.h:5,
                    from /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv_stdarg.h:29,
                    from /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/os-interface.h:27,
                    from /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia/nv.c:12:
   /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/conftest/functions.h:80:2: error: #error wait_on_bit_lock() conftest failed!
      80 | #error wait_on_bit_lock() conftest failed!
         |  ^~~~~

...
  |                                                   ^
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_phys_to_dma':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:703:12: error: implicit declaration of function 'phys_to_dma'; did you mean 'nv_phys_to_dma'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  703 |     return phys_to_dma(dev, pa);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |            nv_phys_to_dma
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_vmalloc':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:521:33: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
  521 |         NV_MEMDBG_ADD(ptr, size);
      |                                 ^
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_ioremap':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:535:33: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
  535 |         NV_MEMDBG_ADD(ptr, size);
      |                                 ^
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_ioremap_cache':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:549:33: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
  549 |         NV_MEMDBG_ADD(ptr, size);
      |                                 ^
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_ioremap_wc':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:579:33: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
  579 |         NV_MEMDBG_ADD(ptr, size);
      |                                 ^
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_vmap':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:666:51: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
  666 |         NV_MEMDBG_ADD(ptr, page_count * PAGE_SIZE);
      |                                                   ^
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_phys_to_dma':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:703:12: error: implicit declaration of function 'phys_to_dma'; did you mean 'nv_phys_to_dma'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  703 |     return phys_to_dma(dev, pa);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |            nv_phys_to_dma
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_is_dma_direct':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1234:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'dma_is_direct'; did you mean 'd_is_dir'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1234 |     if (dma_is_direct(get_dma_ops(dev)))
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         d_is_dir
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function 'nv_is_dma_direct':
/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1234:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'dma_is_direct'; did you mean 'd_is_dir'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1234 |     if (dma_is_direct(get_dma_ops(dev)))
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         d_is_dir
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:244: /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia/procfs_nvswitch.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:244: /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/nvidia/i2c_nvswitch.o] Error 1
make[3]: Target '/tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel/' not remade because of errors.
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.11.0-13-generic/Makefile:1931: /tmp/selfgz6178/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02/kernel] Error 2
make[2]: Target 'modules' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:224: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Target 'modules' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.11.0-13-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:80: modules] Error 2
ERROR: The nvidia kernel module was not created.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.

What are the NVIDIA Developer Resources Contact's information to help get this fixed?  Or else there is the novidea driver?

Generally best not install the .run file. You have to in effect reinstall with every kernel update. Install instructions server or terminal
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation The recommended one is normally best. One much newer may not even be better as designed for newer hardware to support features not on an older board/chip. Shows available drivers, but better now to use Ubuntu repository
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
